# Text replacement efficiency

Tags: java, string, performance

An extension to my previous question:
[Text cleaning and replacement: delete \n from a text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542226/text-cleaning-and-replacement-delete-n-from-a-text-in-java)

I am cleaning this incoming text, which comes from a database with irregular text. That means, there' s no standard or rules. Some contain HTML characters like &reg, &trade, &lt, and others come in this form: &#8221, &#8211, etc. Other times I just get the HTML tags with < and >.

I am using String.replace to replace the characters by their meaning (this should be fine since I'm using UTF-8 right?), and replaceAll() to remove the HTML tags with a regular expression.

Other than one call to the replace() function for each replacement, and compiling the **HTML** tags regular expression, is there any recommendation to make this replacement efficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first suggestion is to measure the performance of the simplest way of doing it (which is probably multiple replace/replaceAll calls). Yes, it's potentially inefficient. Quite often the simplest way of doing this is inefficient. You need to ask yourself: **how much do you care?**

Do you have sample data and a threshold at which point the performance is acceptable? If you don't, that's the first port of call. Then test the naive implementation, and see whether it really *is* a problem. (Bear in mind that string replacement is almost certainly only *part* of what you're doing. As you're fetching the text from a database to start with, that *may* well end up being the bottleneck.)

Once you've determined that the replacement really is the bottleneck, it's worth performing some tests to see which *bits* of the replacement are causing the biggest problem - it sounds like you're doing several different kinds of replacement. The more you can narrow it down, the better: you may find that the real bottleneck in the simplest code is caused by something which is easy to make efficient in a *reasonably* simple way, whereas trying to optimise *everything* would be a lot harder.

Comment: +1 because you're right even though adding to the 35k seems just wrong. Where will it end...?

Comment: @SteveB: You'll be glad to hear that upvoting me at this time of day makes no odds to my rep.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to run into performance bottlenecks with replace with replaceAll.

If you want to increase performance

1. don't use replace - strings are immutable. Will create copies each time you call replace
2. don't use regular expressions (replaceAll) - though being compiled it's not as bad.
3. parse and replace your own strings using StringBuilder

Some code on your end might help discussion.

```
String str = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  char toAppend = 'a';
  switch (str.charAt(i)) {
     case '&' : toAppend = '&'; break;
     case ...
      ...
      default: toAppend = str.charAt(i);
    }
   sb.append(toAppend);
  }
```

this is from: [Sun Forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=723094&start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

String replacement is Java is very slow, i think you should use faster language

here you have code sample how to replace string in assembly

http://szabgab.com/talks/fundamentals_of_perl/replace-string-in-assembly-code.html