# Java replace special characters in a string

Tags: java, java-5

I have a string like this:

```
BEGIN\n\n\n\nTHIS IS A STRING\n\nEND
```

And  I want to remove all the new line characters and have the result as :

```
BEGIN THIS IS A STRING END
```

How do  i accomplish this? The standard API functions will not work because of the escape sequence in my experience.

Comment: So you have literal `\n`? No actual line breaks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text cleaning and replacement: delete \n from a text in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542226/text-cleaning-and-replacement-delete-n-from-a-text-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `replace('\n', ' ')` will cause the string to become:

```
 BEGIN    THIS IS A STRING  END
      ****                **
```

where the `*`'s are spaces. If you want single spaces, try `replaceAll("[\r\n]{2,}", " ")`

And in case they're no line breaks but literal `"\n"`'s wither try:

```
replace("\\n", " ")
```

or:

```
replaceAll("(\\\\n){2,}", " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");` - this is called double escaping :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "BEGIN\n\n\n\nTHIS IS A STRING\n\nEND;";

str = str.replaceAll("\\\n", " ");

// Remove extra white spaces
while (str.indexOf("  ") > 0) {
   str = str.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

Comment: This gives the exact expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
String s = "BEGIN\n\n\n\nTHIS IS A STRING\n\nEND";
String t = s.replaceAll("[\n]+", " ");
System.out.println(t);
```

The key is the reg-ex.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the standard API will work, but you may have to double escape ("\\n").

Comment: Like : str.replaceAll("\\n", "")  ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually code in Java, but a quick search leads me to believe that String.trim should work for you. It says that it removes leading and trailing white space along with \n \t etc...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will help,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader("BEGIN\n\n\n\nTHIS IS A STRING\n\nEND "));
    String out = "";
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        out += sc.next() + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(out);
```