# Removing new lines from output text using pdfbox

Tags: java, regex, string, pdfbox

Using pdfbox I can get text from PDF. The text goes like this:

> ```
> abcabcabs  Phrase 1 123 abc 123
>
> abcabcabs 123 abcabcabs 123 abc 123  Phrase 2 abcabcabs 
>
> 123 abc 123
> ```

Using regex I was trying to get content from `Phrase 1` to `Phrase 2` but it looks like I can only get text between words that are in one line.
I was trying to remove `\n` using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542226/text-cleaning-and-replacement-delete-n-from-a-text-in-java) methods, but my text file is always with new lines like above.

How can I get text in a one giant string without lines and print it on screen?

Comment: Well, if you first get it as a string, you can then call on that string `replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(),"");` or if the separator is different from the system's, say `\n`, then `replaceAll("\n","")`. Note: you could do the same thing with `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
stripper.setLineSeparator(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Phrase 1((?:.|\r?\n)*?)Phrase 2"` should capture everything between `"Phrase 1"` and `"Phrase 2"`, including new lines.
See this for an explaination: http://regex101.com/r/vH9hV1

Alternatively, you can just use the "dotall" flag which makes `.` match everything *including* new lines: http://regex101.com/r/aE9dP6